# How can i access a Text view and print

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I need to access a text view which is present inside Linear layout and print the text using gettext()?

Layout looks like:

Linearlayout
   Linearlayout
      Imageview
   Relativelayout
      Textview

Answer (score 0):

The layouts around your `TextView` wouldn't matter unless you are playing with their `Visibility`.

The `Activity` in which you are accessing your `TextView` needs its call to:
 `setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);`

use `textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewId);`
to map your `textView` and then can

```
textView.getText()
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html

http://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-layout-and-id-attribute/

Answer (score 0):

Create a `linearLayoutObject` for first layout and then create another object for `TextView`.

```
UiObject lLayout = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className(LinearLayout.class.getName()).index(1));

UiObject tView = lLayout.getChild(new UiSelector().className(TextView.class.getName()).index(1));

String tDetails = tView.getText();
```

Now you can use `tDetails` for comparison or other purpose.